# Terminate the SSL at an apache instead of ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I want to migrate my platoform built with PHP/APACHE to AWS Cloud. My application serves multiple website with different domains and SSL Certificates. I can use only 50 certificate with AWS Application Load Balancer ( this is the hard limit ), so I am planning a different solution.

Can I use the Network Load Balancer and forward port 443 to my ECS instance ( Fargate ) without attaching a certificate and then terminate the SSL on apache instead of ELB?

In this way I can bypass the certificate limit and manage it with virtual host.

I'm right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the NLB to route TCP/443 traffic to your ECS cluster. NLB does not terminate SSL, it just passes on the packets.

Alternately you could use multiple ALBs.